# How to keep a hidden dropdown open on next page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a dropdown with `<a>` tag inside. It is `hidden` per default, there is also a caret next to the dropdown which gets rotated down when dropdown is open. Now what i want is when i click on the dropdown and click an Element of it, the dropdown should stay open (caret down) and the element should stay selected in the next page (if possible). I dont really want to use `localStorage` or `Sessions` for this example. Can anyone help me out or give an example how this could be done?

```
<div class="client dropdownSideBar" id="cl">
    <button class="dropdown-btn font_24 font_white">
        CLIENT
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="dropdown-menu">
        <a>Element1</a><br>
        <a>Element2</a><br>
    </div>
</div>

/* keep the caret aligned */
#cl .dropdown-btn::before {
    margin-left: 115px;
}
.dropdown-btn::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\25BC"; /* caret content */
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    float: right;
}
.dropdownSideBar.is-open .dropdown-btn:before {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
    color: white;
}

.dropdownSideBar.is-open .font_white {
    background-color: #575757;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.dropdownSideBar.is-open .dropdown-container {
    display: block;
}
/* hidden by default, make the content shifts under the title */
.dropdown-container {
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #575757;
}
.dropdown-container a {color: white; padding-left: 30px;}
.dropdown-container a:hover {background-color: #414141;}
```

The JavaScript to display the dropdown menu when the client is clicked and to keep just one dropdown open at once

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;
var indexOfSelectedElement = window.location.pathname;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-container')).forEach(el => {
        //hide the nonclicked 
        if (el !== dropdownContent) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") 
        dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    else
        dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  });
}
//get the three Dropdowns

const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdownSideBar");
dropdowns.forEach(el => {
    const button = el.querySelector(".dropdown-btn");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const caret = document.getElementById('caret');
        // Close all
        [...dropdowns].filter(x => x != el).forEach(el => el.classList.remove("is-open"));
        // Toggle one
        el.classList.toggle("is-open");
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dgLfjxn2/
Update: i tried to solve this with the URL, Problem i am facing is that the caret isnt rotated and when i click the client the after selector is applied. Still getting no Element selected though.

```
var menu = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu');
var client = document.getElementById('clientButton');
var id = indexOfSelectedElement.substr(14, indexOfSelectedElement.lastIndexOf('/') - 14);
if(indexOfSelectedElement.substr(0, 14) === "/fleet/client/") {
    menu.style.display = 'block';
    menu.style.backgroundColor = '#575757';
    client.style.backgroundColor = '#575757';
    client.style.color = 'white';

    //TODO: keep the clicked client selected on the redirected page?, rotate the caret, when client is clicked again backgroundColor and caret are in the after selector.
}
```

Comment: Why not set a URL parameter for this?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, i have tried this but didnt actually get to make it work..

Comment: Where's your attempt to use this approach? If you could share it, others could check for errors

Comment: What's wrong with localStorage? It's easy to use

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated the question with something i have tried, for a better understanding you can just create an empty page where the data would be redirected.

Comment: @expressjs123 Because it is complicated for this example, for me at least because iam new to web dev.

Comment: add hrref and id to anchor href="page/?item=element1" id="element1". In the page you should get item value from location and search anchor by id with that value var a = document.querySelector('#' + itempar), finally you should find and click related button  a.closest('dropdownsidebar').querySelector('button').click() and add a class to anchor to style as selected

Comment: @Lety i retrieved the Index so far. but couldnt do a valid search with the querySelector. here is what i have done `var path = window.location.pathname; //full path
var pathIndex = path.substr(14, (path.lastIndexOf('/')-14)); // id for example 1 for first element
var a=document.querySelector('path');` could you maybe edit this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `href` and `id` to your anchor, for example:

```
<div class="client dropdownSideBar" id="cl">
    <button class="dropdown-btn font_24 font_white">
        CLIENT
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="/destination/?item=element1" id="element1">Element1</a><br>
        <a href="/destination/?item=element2" id="element2">Element2</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

In `/destination/` page you should include your css and javascript code plus this:

```
var url_string = window.location.href;   // get the url
var url = new URL(url_string);
var menuItem = url.searchParams.get("item"); // get item parameter value

// get the dom object of the anchor clicked in previous page
var a = document.querySelector('#' + menuItem);
// find and click related button this should open dropdown menu and rotate caret
a.closest('dropdownsidebar').querySelector('button').click();
// Finally add class to style selected menu item
a.className += " item-selected";
```

For example:

```
item-selected {
   background-color: '#575757',
   color: 'white'
}
```